# How to send html mail with mailchimp using python

Tags: python, django, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am trying send promotional mails to the users using mailchimp for my django application.I have created campaign and list.Now I want to add html template to the campaign through api.I can do this by the send_mail function in Django. But I want to send as promotional email via mailchimp

Is there any way to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

You must use their service ‘mandrill’. 
The official package for python is here: https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/index.python.html

If you use it with Django, have a look at “djrill”: http://djrill.readthedocs.io/en/v2.1/